# Derive the Probability of Default (PD) of private companies with Merton Model

Tags: equities, capm, models, stochastic, debt

Do you know a well used method how to calculate the PD of private companies using the Merton Model.
The main challenges I am facing is to get the appropriate volatility of the assets and the drift.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Do have a look at slides #8ff here https://www.bot.or.th/Thai/FinancialInstitutions/Highlights/IFRS9_Doc/The%20Merton%20Model.pdf

Effectively, you can either solve a bivariate equation system (numerically), or you introduce some iterative scheme - both are explained on the slides, or may give you a hint at where to start from there.

Comment: I will have to compute the PD for companies which are not listed on the stock exchange. The companies are also relativally young, so that I do not have many data points for the history

Comment: Then, maybe, you might need to resort to fundamentals-based credit risk estimators in order to calibrate a Merton-like default model, no?

Comment: Your mean estimating the PD with fundamental-based credit risk estimators and then find the drift and volatility of the stochastic equation?